# Retain element/scope state when moving controller within DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an angular application, I want to move an element from one part of the DOM tree to another, without having to reload the controller/s attached to the moved element.

I have created a simplified plunker to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/sqBRM3ZQ5G9xpiNd1MXm?p=preview

In this plunker, the only data to be retained is the toggler state, but in reality it could be a very large amount of data, which may require a lot of effort to initialise.

What I want to do is to be able to move template 1 from directive 1 into directive 2, but I want to retain the state of the toggler. In this scenario, if you click the toggler to make it green, and click on "move from list 1 to 2" twice, it will move it to directive 2 but reset the color to red.

To circumvent this, I can just move the element without notifying angular, but this obviously creates a broken application state.

I thought about just moving the controller from the old scope to the new scope, but I feel that this will cause closure problems as the old controller may be referencing the old element which is no longer in the DOM etc.

Is there a nice way to solve this problem?

Adding some code because StackOverflow requires it, but refer to plunker instead:

```
angular.module('app').controller('bodyController', ['$element', function ($element) {

    this.contents1 = [{
        path: 'template1.html'
    }, {
        path: 'template2.html'
    }];

    this.contents2 = [{
        path: 'template3.html'
    }, {
        path: 'template4.html'
    }];

    this.move12 = function () {
        this.contents2.push(this.contents1.pop());
    };

    this.move21 = function () {
        this.contents1.push(this.contents2.pop());
    };

    this.naiveMove12 = function () {
        var $elem = $($element);
        $elem.find('container-list:eq(0) > div').last()
            .appendTo($elem.find('container-list').eq(1));
    };

    this.naiveMove21 = function () {
        var $elem = $($element);
        $elem.find('container-list:eq(1) > div').last()
            .appendTo($elem.find('container-list').eq(0));
    };

    this.logScope = function () {
        var $elem = $($element);
        [].forEach.call($elem.find('container-list'), function (elem, idx) {
            console.log(idx + ': ', angular.element(elem).isolateScope().containerListCtrl);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Instead of moving stuff, could you not just have the data in a singleton factory. Use that factory also as a event aggregator. Then when you want to move data, you simple remove it from one and load it into the other. Any state can be sent with the event. If you also want to load up different templates you can use `$templateProvider` and `$compile`.

Comment: After loading data cache it in the $rootScope, then you will have access to it in all of your controllers. I tried adding $rootScope to your plunker, but it did not seem to be working. If you are interested in this approach I can show you code for it.

Comment: Think I answered your question below. Check out the plunkr for working solution. Please let me know if you have any questions or if I misunderstood anything at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Coupling application state with view/controller is not the best practice in my experience, but here is a way to do it: **[revised plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yTiXE00WyqFe7XEMNd79?p=preview).**

There are a few small changes in `template1.html`. The only other changes are in `templateController.js`:

```
angular.module('app').controller('templateController', statefulTemplateCtrl());

function statefulTemplateCtrl() {
  var state = {color: 'red'};
  return function(){
    this.state = state;

    // this.color = 'red';

    this.toggleColor = function () {
        state.color = (state.color === 'red') ? 'green' : 'red';
    };
  };
}
```

where the function now used as `templateController` has been configured to maintain reference to a `state` object. Now if you move the template using `bodyCtrl.move12()`, you'll be able to keep accumulated toggle state without breaking your application state. This works because the controller has reference to an external object through a closure. As a result, it can get re-instantiated and recompiled at the new DOM node by `ng-include` without re-instatiating `state`.

**Probably a better way to handle**

Use services and/or the `$scope` events API to share state between different DOM nodes in your application.

Say you have the template, the same one introduced in your plunker:

```
<div ng-class="{ red: (tc.color === 'red'), green: (tc.color === 'green') }" ng-click="tc.toggleColor()">Toggler</div>
```

And you'd like to move the `tc` object, which houses all of your toggle-related state, to another node in the DOM, you can:

- dispatch an event **down the scope heirarchy** with `$scope.$broadcast('nameOfEvent', tc)` if the destination node is a descendent of the source `$scope`
- dispatch an event **up the scope heirarchy** if `$scope.$emit('nameOfEvent', tc)` if the destination node is an ancestor of the source `$scope`
- dispatch an event **to all nodes in your app** by injecting `$rootScope` and `$rootScope.$broadcast('nameOfEvent', tc)` if the destination node can be either.

Invoking any of these methods of the $scope event API will allow you to transmit the data, in this case the `tc` object, from one node to another. The destination controller associated with the destination node can be waiting for the event to be dispatched with a listener function able to receive the transmitted data:

```
function bindDataToController(destinationCtrl){
  return function(event, tc){
    angular.extend(destinationCtrl, tc);
  };
} 

$scope.$on('nameOfEvent', bindDataToController(this));
```

The transmitted data object, `tc`, will get bound to the controller associated with the new destination node upon receipt of the triggered `'nameOfEvent'`. Now that the source data has been merged with the destination controller object, make sure that your destination controller is given the same `controllerAs` name as your source controller, in this case `'tc'`, so that the source template may correctly reference the destination controller once it is ultimately compiled and attached to the destination DOM node (which process is discussed below).

Removing and adding DOM nodes is somewhat trivial as you mentioned, so I haven't discussed it here, but if you'd like easy access to the source view/template to add and remove in any location in your application as necessary, you can use the `$templateCache`.

Back to the toggle example, if your toggle view/template is itself already part of a directive that uses `templateUrl` with the file path `'toggle.html'`, then your template will have already been put to and stored in the `$templateCache` under the key `'toggle.html'`.

In your destination controller, inject `$templateCache`, which will allow you to retrieve the template:

```
 var template = $templateCache.get('toggle.html');
```

Inject $compile into your destination controller and $compile the template with the destination $scope (also injected into the destination controller):

```
var $template = $compile(template)($scope);
```

then append the compiled template to the `$element` (also injected into the destination controller) associated with your destination controller:

```
$element.append($template);
```

If you'd like to only compile and append the `'toggle.html'` template to the DOM upon receipt of the transmitted data, you can place the above imperative compile code inside the return function of `bindDataToController`, registered as the event listener for `'nameOfEvent'`. And there you have it!... A DOM node that has been "moved" with whatever complex state that was previously built up at the source location.